# Access page crashes when running sql query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm new to VBA and Access,  I'm trying to hide a button based upon a bit field in a tsql database, when I comment the line of code that executes the query, the access form loads fine,  when I uncomment it, it crashes.. Please help! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
DoCmd.Maximize

Dim RecordSt As Recordset
Dim dbase As Database
Dim query As String
query = "select * from tblsetup;"
Set RecordSt = dbase.OpenRecordset(query)    'Line of code that crashes page
'If RecordSt.Fields("ValidateChecks").Value = 0 Then
    'cmdValidate.Visible = False
'Else
    'cmdValidate.Visible = True
'End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set dbase equal to anything.  If the table is a linked table, you want dbase to be equal to CurrentDB:

```
Set dbase = CurrentDB
```

Put that above the "Set Recordst" statement

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! Will mark as answer when timer runs out.